# Adding a symlink to setup.py sdist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, symlink, setup.py

I'd like to create a "python3 setup.py sdist" distribution to make myprogram.py available at pypi.org via pip. 'myprogram.py' needs some additional files (e.g., conf, images). Say, we have the following layout:

```
myprogram.py
myprogram.conf
images ---
       image1.png
       image2.png
        ...
other_data ---
       other_data1.txt
       other_data2.txt
       images --> images
```

I am not able to find a way to "install" the symlink 'images --> images' in dir 'other_data' in ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
Something like

```
recursive-include other_data *
```

in 'manifest.in' or

```
'data_files=['other_data', ['other_data1.txt',
                            'images']),
```

in setup.py doesn't work.
How symlinks may be added the proper way?

Comment: You mean, the package will never work on Windows?

Comment: Yes, most users will work on GNU/Linux - btw, I thought, Win7+ can handle symlinks, too?